# Flutter 2.8.0 will not deploy and run project on iOS simulator (was working on 2.5.3)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, authentication

My dev environment is as follows:

- Mac Mini M1
- Mac OS Monterey
- Visual Studio Code
- Flutter 2.8.0
- iPhone 12 Pro Max (iOS simulator)

Flutter dependencies:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_core: ^1.10.5
firebase_auth: ^3.3.3
google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
flutter_login_facebook: ^1.2.0
provider: ^6.0.1

When I try to build and run the application, I get the following error:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           18.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/daoudmalikyar/Documents/dev/Udemy/flutter_firebase/time_tracker/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found
@import firebase_auth;
~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
/Users/daoudmalikyar/Documents/dev/Udemy/flutter_firebase/time_tracker/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
/Users/daoudmalikyar/Documents/dev/Udemy/flutter_firebase/time_tracker/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)

I've tried several potential fixes found on the web but none seem to fix the issue.  Again, this code was running fine under 2.5.3.
When I try building the project in XCode, I get the same error that 'firebase_auth' was not found.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is `fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found @import firebase_auth;` delete the pods and install manually. Maybe it will, I migrated the flutter today and I had no problems with firebase auth

Comment: @Chance Hi Chance, are you on a Mac using Apple silicon (M1 or higher)?  If so, can you provide the exact steps you took to delete the pods and install manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding three lines to ios/Podfile:

```
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
+    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
+      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
+   end
   end
 end
```

Check this comment for more information:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94914#issuecomment-992898782

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `cd ios`
3. `rm -rf Podfile.lock`
4. Replace your Podfile with the one which is down below and set the target iOS platform in the second line
5. `pod install`
6. `cd ..`
7. `flutter run`

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|

  puts 'Determining pod project minimal deployment target'

  pods_project = installer.pods_project
  deployment_target_key = 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
  deployment_targets = pods_project.build_configurations.map{ |config| config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] }
  minimal_deployment_target = deployment_targets.min_by{ |version| Gem::Version.new(version) }

  puts 'Minimal deployment target is ' + minimal_deployment_target
  puts 'Setting each pod deployment target to ' + minimal_deployment_target

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings[deployment_target_key] = minimal_deployment_target
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem. (I have the exact same type of error as author). Downgrading is the only option for now..

Comment: @HugHunter How did you perform the downgrade?  When I run "flutter version", I get command not found?  I definitely have flutter/bin in my path.  Thanks

Comment: @dmalikyar use "flutter downgrade v2.5.3" to downgrade, it might say successful but still show 2.8 in IDE. In that case run the command again so it downloads the old version